# return a struct array and use at main class

Tags: c++

A bit of information

```
Parent Class: Vehicle
Child Class: Car & Motorcycle
```

I got a `struct` which is

```
struct Point 
{
    int x,y;
};
```

and i got a `setPoint` function at `Car` & `Motorcycle` which do the following

since `Car` got 4 wheels and `Motorcycle` got 2 wheels.

`Car` will have this function

```
class Car : public Vehicle
{
private:
    Point wheelPoint[4]; // if motorcycle then its wheelPoint[2]
public:
    Point getPoint();
    void setPoint();
}

void Car::setPoint()
{
    int xData,yData;

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
         cout << "Please enter X  :" ;
         cin >> xData;
         cout << "Please enter Y  :" ;
         cin >> yData;
    }//end for loop
}//end setPoint
```

so i got a `getPoint` function also..

```
Point Car::getPoint()
{
     return wheelPoint;
}
```

The issue is at my main.cpp , i did the following

```
int main()
{
     VehicleTwoD *vehicletwod[100];

     //assuming just car but there motorcycle too
     Car *mCar = new Car();
     Point myPoint;

     vechicletwod[0] = mCar;
     //here i did the setpoint, set other variable

     //then when i try retrieve
     myPoint = Car->getPoint();
     //no error till here.

     cout << sizeof(myPoint);
}
```

no matter its motorcycle or car, the result always stay at 4, it wont be 2 for motorcycle and 4 for car. i not sure whats wrong

Assuming i did the setpoint for motorcycle too. both return same result, is my contain Point myPoint in main class unsuitable to contain a wheelPoint[array]

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Nowhere, my tired mind is playing tricks on me.

Comment: getPoint() returns one Point when wheelPoint is an array of Point: this code doesn't compile.

Comment: Using a `std::vector<Point>` instead of an array would solve some of your problems. And also allow for 3-wheeled vehicles (both cars and motorcycles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(myPoint)` should return the size of the type `Point` (well, your code doesn't compile to start with, but if it did, that's what it would return). `Car` and `Motorcycle` don't come into discussion.

One alternative is to have a `virtual` function is `Vechicle`:

```
class Vechicle
{
    virtual int getNoWheels() = 0;
};
```

which you override in `Car` and `Motorcycle`:

```
class Car : public Vechicle
{
    int getNoWheels() { return 4; }
};
class Motorcycle : public Vechicle
{
    int getNoWheels() { return 2; }
};
```

and then call. Something like:

```
VehicleTwoD *vehicletwod[100];
vehicletwod[0] = new Car;
vehicletwod[1] = new Motorcycle;

vehicletwod[0]->getNoWheels(); //returns 4
vehicletwod[1]->getNoWheels(); //returns 2
```

Another alternative is to hold a `std::vector<Point>` as a member in `Vehicle`:

```
class Vehicle
{
   std::vector<Point> wheels;
   Vehicle(int noWheels) : wheels(noWheels) {}
   int getNoWheels() { return wheels.size() }
};
```

and initialize it depending on the actual class, e.g.:

```
class Car
{
   Car() : Vehicle(4) {}
};
```

Also, I doubt:

```
myPoint = Car->getPoint();
```

compiles, since `Car` is a type, not a pointer to an object. Next time, reduce your code to the minimum and **post the actual code**.